# Order List by category

Tags: c#

I have a List which contains a list of categories, in these categories is also a list that contains products.

I want to order the products by a certain products category like Eggs, Milk, Water, Ice

here is what I have:

```
foreach (var cat in data.List)
        {
            if (cat.Id == "ProductType1")
            {
                cat.Modules.OrderBy(f => f.ProdType == "Eggs").
                    ThenBy(f => f.ProdType == "Milk");                  
            }
        }
```

but this doesn't work and if I have a longer list of prodtype then it will be a lot of code to write down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an inline if statement in your code to set a sort key:

```
foreach (var cat in data.List)
{
   if (cat.Id == "ProductType1")
   {
      cat.Modules.OrderBy(f => 
                   f.ProdType == "Eggs" ? 1 : f.ProdType=="Milk" ? 2 : 3 );                  
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have a long list of lookups you can use a switch instead:

```
foreach (var cat in data.List)
{
   if (cat.Id == "ProductType1")
   {
      cat.Modules.OrderBy (s => 
         {
            int i = 0;
            switch(s)
            {
                case "Eggs": i=1; break;
                case "Milk": i=2; break;
                case "Water": i=3;break;
                default: i=4; break;
            }
            return i;
        });                  
   }
}
```

Comment: what if ProdType values are more than 3? :P)

Comment: That was just an example, you would have to extend the if clause, not particularly nice. Your answer is probably neater

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan Amended answer to allow the switch statement to make longer lists easier to handle

Comment: @SteveFord thanks that will do it.  I had to assign  it like

var newlist = cat.Modules.OrderBy (s => 
         {
            int i = 0;
            switch(s)
            {
                case "Eggs": i=1; break;
                case "Milk": i=2; break;
                case "Water": i=3;break;
                default: i=4; break;
            }
            return i;
        });    
cat.Modules = newlist;

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy needs a key (property in this case) against which it orders the collection, so you are using it wrongly. One way I could think of is like below

```
var result = cat.Modules.Where(f => f.ProdType == "Eggs")
             .Union(cat.Modules.Where(f => f.ProdType == "Milk"))
             .Union(cat.Modules.Where(f => f.ProdType == "Water")).ToList();
```

Comment: what are the purpose of .Select(p => p) es?

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear question, but this is probably what you are looking form

```
var orderDict = new Dictionary<string, int>{
      {"Eggs", 0},
      {"Milk", 1},
      {"Water", 2}
}
var sortedbyCat =data.List.OrderBy(g => orderDict[g.Key]);
```

Comment: Be aware that if the prodType doesn't exist in your orderDict then an exception is thrown. You could do OrderBy (s => {int i = 99;orderDict.TryGetValue(s, out i); return i; } ); instead; If you can guarantee that the item will be in your dictionary, you can do the simpler OrderBy (s => orderDict[s] ); without the need for the GroupBy

Comment: group by removed, regarding dictionary, also right but it is not clear in question so yep, it should be handled

Comment: does TryGetValue O(1) also ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat.Modules.Sort((a, b) => a.ProdType.CompareTo(b.ProdType));
```

this will order your products **ALPHABETICALLY** by `ProdType`